# Cannot find a supported version of tflite-runtime for docker image to dockerize a flask app

Tags: pandas, docker, numpy, flask, tflite

I have a list of python base images which I can use for a specific project, and I need to install tflite-runtime for reducing the image size.
I have tried installing the tflite-runtime on python 3.6-slim base image it worked when I used the proper version.
But the provided base images don't support any of the tflite-runtime versions I have tried.
I have tried installing using direct pip and downloading the whl file, anyway I get the same error when building the image: (I have tried various versions)

Error:tflite_runtime-2.13.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I can only use tflite-runtime in my image, but the base image lists are (some are custom):
1.Python:3.10.4-alpine3.16
2.python:3.11.0-alpine3.17
3.python:3.11.1-alpine3.17
4.python:3.11.4-alpine3.18
5.python:3.11.4-slim
6.python:alpine3.14
7.python-base-tools:1.12.0
8.python-base-tools:3.9.6-custom-alpine

Also I'm getting an error when installing pandas from the requirements.txt. (pandas without specifying any particular version)

I need a supported version of tflite-runtime and pandas for builing the image, this is not any arm64 machine or something like that, I'm using the tflite-runtime for reducing the image size and loading time inside a flask app.
Also an error is blocking the image build in pip install pandas.